# How to use an button on homescreen widget?

Tags: android, widget

I have an widget, with an button and an imagebutton.
I want that if you click the imagebutton, there opens an transparant activity with an edittext.
For example we fill in 01
Than when you click the normal button, it will load an webview that shows html file 01.html.
Is this possible?

The code i have is:

```
 package com.kerk.liedboek.widget;

 import android.app.Notification;
 import android.app.NotificationManager;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.RemoteViews;
 import android.widget.Toast;

  public class main extends AppWidgetProvider {

      public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
      public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";

      @Override 
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager 
 appWidgetManager, 
        int[] appWidgetIds) { 
            Intent i = new Intent(context, edit.class); 
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, i,0); 
            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), 
 R.layout.main); 
            rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_one, pi); 

            Intent i2 = new Intent(context, webview.class); 
            PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, i2,0); 
            RemoteViews rv2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), 
 R.layout.main); 
            rv2.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_two, pi2); 

    }
}
```

I'm new to android, and i now i'm an newb. But i hope you understand me and you can help me.
Gaauwe

Edit:

My logcat is:

07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.liedboek.widget.aantekening: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liedboek.widget.aantekening
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1773)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liedboek.widget.aantekening
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1764)
07-09 14:19:31.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     ... 10 more
07-09 14:19:31.101: WARN/ActivityManager(69): Process com.liedboek.widget has crashed too many times: killing!

But my code is another code, but also an button widget:

package com.liedboek.widget;

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.PendingIntent; 
 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.RemoteViews;

 public class main extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";

@Override 
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager 
appWidgetManager, 
  int[] appWidgetIds) { 
    // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, aantekening.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
    // to the button
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_one, pendingIntent);

    // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views); 



  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `getBroadcast` you may want to use `getActivity`.

Comment: I don't understand you. can you give me an example on the web or can you give me an code?

Comment: Please, read the code you paste (I'm guessing you didn't write it or something)... then you will understand ;)

Comment: I put it in my code, but when i click an button, there will come nothing. I don't understand wy?

Comment: Oh man... you lazy... if you wrote your code, you know you wrote this: `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`, it will allows you to send broadcast messages when user clicks on the widget item. However, you want to launch an Activity, so you must use `PendingIntent.getActivity` instead.

Comment: well i'm sorry, I understand you now but i don't now how to launch it. i have:Intent i = new Intent(context, edit.class); 
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, zoek.class);                          But that also doesn't work: it says: The method getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (Context, int, Class<edit>, int)               
                RemoteViews rv = newRemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
R.layout.configure);
                rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_one, pi);

Comment: @user828399: Restore your code to the state that it is shown in your question. Then, position your cursor in your editor on the `(` that follows `getBroadcast`. Press the BACKSPACE key nine times. Type in `Activity`. Repeat this process for the other `getBroadcast` call, to change `Broadcast` to `Activity`. Save. Compile. Run.

Comment: this still doesn't work. When i put the widget on my screen it says: forced close, and then when i click an button there don't happen any thing

Comment: paste the logcat after the the crash

Comment: Can you also paste the code you are using now? It must be different than the one you pasted days ago.